# Finding the critical points of $f(x, y) = x^3 - 3xy + y^3$ - Why does expression selection for substitution matter?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Finding the critical points of $f(x, y) = x^3 - 3xy + y^3$.

My solution and reasoning are as follows.

$f(x, y) = x^3 - 3xy + y^3$

$\nabla f(x, y) = (3x^2 - 3y, -3x + 3y^2)$

$\nabla f(x, y) = (3x^2 - 3y, -3x + 3y^2) = (0, 0)$

$\therefore 3x^2 - 3y = 0$

$\implies 3x^2 = 3y$

$\implies x^2 = y$

$\therefore 3y^2 - 3x = 0$

Substituting $x^2 = y$ into $3y^2 - 3x = 0$ will give us the values of $x$ for which $3y^2 - 3x = 0$.

$3x^4 - 3x = 0$

$\implies $x^4 - x = 0$

$\implies x(x^3 - 1) = 0$

$\implies x = 0, 1$

Substituting $x = 0$ and $x = 1$ into $3y^2 - 3x = 0$ will give us values of $y$ where $\nabla f(0, y) = (0, 0)$ and $\nabla f(1, y) = (0, 0)$.

$3y^2 - 3 = 0$

$\implies 3y^2 = 3$

$\implies y^2 = 1$

$\implies y = \pm 1$

**HOWEVER**, only $\nabla f(1, 1) = (0, 0)$.

If I had substituted $x = 0, 1$ into $3x^2 - 3y = 0$ (the other expression) and solved for $y$, I would have gotten the correct solution for both of my $y$ values.

$3(0)^2 - 3y = 0$

$\implies y = 0$

$\therefore \nabla f(0, 0) = (0, 0)$

$3(1)^2 - 3y = 0$

$\implies y = 1$

$\therefore \nabla f(1, 1) = (0, 0)$

The other solutions of $x$ and $y$ are all false. Why is this? Is my reasoning is incorrect? Is my methodology incorrect? **Why does the expression you choose to substitute back into for values of $x$ or $y$ matter? What is the reasoning behind this?**

Thank you.

Comment: There was no error. Because in some steps you only had an implication ($\Longrightarrow$) instead of an equivalence ($\Longleftrightarrow$) it means that you may have introduced extraneous solutions that need to be tested against the original system of equations anyway. When there are alternative ways of processing a system of equations, the correct choices answers will appear in all of them, but the number of extraneous solutions may vary.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Which steps are you referring to?

Comment: A back substitution, for example, is only one-way logic because at that point one typically ignores some of the earlier equations and only uses their corollaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obtained that the critical points of $f$ are those for which 
$$y^2 =x$$
$$x^2=y$$

Note that if you find that $x=0$ then forcefully $y=0^2=0$. Similarly, if $x=1$ then forcefully $y=1^2=1$. Because $y=x^2$ is a square, you cannot have $y=-1$ a negative number, so you can safely discard it.

This is the intersection of two parabolas (draw them), which you can check happens at $(1,1)$ and $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks. I can see that I got $x^2 = y$ but where did you get $y^2 = x$ from?

Comment: @ThePointer From $-3x+3y^2$, the second coordiante of $\nabla f$.

Comment: But I'm not explicitly finding $y^2 = x$? I'm only finding $x^2 = y$ Can you please explain what I'm misunderstanding here?

Comment: You wrote $\therefore 3y^2 - 3x = 0$ in your post, didn't you? Now clear up that $3$.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. It all makes sense now! Thank you very much! :)